# Get the featured image url of clicked post

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, custom-post-type, bootstrap-modal

How can I display the featured image of a post in a modal along with it's content.

With the help of a few online threads on similar issues, I tried this:

```
<?php
    if ( has_post_thumbnail()) {
        echo '<a href="' . get_permalink($post->ID) . '" >';
            the_post_thumbnail('my_feature_image', array( 'class' => "someName" ));
        echo '</a>';
    }
?>
```

Which unfortunately returns the same featured image for all posts.

On the same `header.php` where the modal is found, the following is there (above the modal divs):

```
  //on the homepage... check for the post URL...
  //do we have a custom permalink incoming....
  $perma = false; if (isset($wp_query->query_vars['phpost_slug'])) #WHFIX 24/03/2015: 
  $perma = $wp_query->query_vars['phpost_slug'];
  if($perma){
  //we don't want to return a 404
  $wp_query->set( 'is_404', false );
  $phid = get_page_by_path($perma, OBJECT, 'post');
  $postvote = get_post_meta($phid->ID, 'epicredvote' ,true);
  $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $phid->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );

  $pluginfeat = get_post_meta($phid->ID,'phog',true);
  $desc = get_post($phid->ID)->post_content;
```

link to site: https://goo.gl/30a3QQ [Click on the post's row to open the modal.]

**UPDATE**

I tried removing the  anchor tags as well as the classes like this and it still isn't working:

```
<?php
    if ( has_post_thumbnail()) {
            the_post_thumbnail();
    }
?>
```

Comment: the code above needs to be in a loop to work, are you running a loop where its located? This may be more efficient to append the image url and content into a js object from within your page content loop and simply create onclick.

Comment: @David I dont think it is. However for the main post thumbnails, the same above code snippet work ( https://goo.gl/30a3QQ )

Comment: If you click on any post text, a modal comes up with the relevant post content and it's heading

Comment: But unfortunately, the image remains the same on all posts.

Comment: @David I tried removing the anchor tags as well as the classes as shown in the updated part of the question but it keeps showing the same image.

Comment: treat the loop as a foreach statement, it looks like you are only outputting 1 post. You need to create a custom loop to loop over your query to build the html with each posts information otherwise you only build 1. But you said this is not the case?  .. i havent checked your js as there is loads on the page, but where is the onclick function set? if you upload the header code (mayb pastebin?), template code and js code i can have a look..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element you are changing is only the html wireframe for the onclick handlers to populate, the problem is, it didnt include a image on the original so you need to add that functionality. something like this should work (add to your footer)

```
var eventTargets=document.querySelectorAll('.hunt-row');

[].forEach.call(eventTargets, function(t){
    t.addEventListener('click', function(){
        console.log('clicked');
        var img= this.querySelector('img').src;

        //bind new src to modal thumb, this is not ideal as there is only a class rather than a id...

        document.querySelector('.modal-thumb').src= img;

    }, false);
});
```

Of course, im not sure how nice it will play with the other click handlers, you may need to remove the default and write your own to populate the model box onclick.

Comment: Firstly, I would like to sincerely thank you for the patience in helping me with this good sir. So I added the above in the footer within `script` tags and the same image still displays on all posts unfortunately :(

Comment: any errors on the console (chrome inspect element and console...)? I put in a console.log so at least you will know the event is firing, you may need to remove.listeners and just populate from a custom function, i had a quick look at the js but there is a load of it to go through.

Comment: Checking asap. One sec

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: t.addeventlistener is not a function`
`Uncaught Error: init not called with valid version` The console echoed these two errors. How do I remove listeners as you mentioned?

Comment: sorry misspelled eventlistener, it should be .addEventListener i updated it above.

Comment: You sir are the best!!